# LibreOffice Regex match entire string with Regex()

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

In `J6` in my calc workbook exists the text

```
Greg Zuerlein kicks off 65 yards returned by Jaydon Mickens for 20 yards (tackle by Jayron Kearse)
```

the formula below is in another cell:

`=REGEX($J6,"^.+returned by.+ for ([0-9]+)|(no gain).*$","$1")`

My goal is that the formula returns the text `20`. None work, and I always end up with this output:

```
20 yards (tackle by Jayron Kearse)
```

Changing the regex pattern so that it doesn't have `$` or `^` doesn't change the output. Changing the `$` into `{0,}` also does not change the output. My thought process was that the regular expression was supposed to be greedy by nature, and collect all the chars it could before matching, but that doesn't seem to be happening here. Could there be an issue with capture groups using alternation?

I've done similar searches using other programs and I'm stumped as to why this doesn't work here. Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to feed your regex to the regex demo linked by @Wiktor. You'll see that the "|" sign has a different effect then you've expected. It doesn't just alternate between digits and "no gain", but it divides the entire search pattern into two parts. I'm not sure why the first part also matches the text after "20", but it already helps to put the "digits/no gain" alternative into brackets. too: `for (([0-9]+)|(no gain))`.

Comment: I didn't explain it well in the original post, but yes, the "no gain" text was important to capture as well (in a different cell; this formula was meant to act on a range of data). I was cautious of putting the parentheticals around the entire alternation (I didn't know you could do an alternation in-line like that!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^.+returned by.+ for ([0-9]+).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aX723K/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string/line
- `.+` - one or more chars as many as possible
- `returned by` - a literal text
- `.+` - one or more chars as many as possible
- `for`   - a literal text
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): one or more digits
- `.*` - zero or more chars as many as possible.

Comment: You can even drop the start of string/line anchors. Just search for one or more digits after "r": `".*r ([0-9]+).*"`

Comment: @tohuwawohu Removing `$` in these cases with `.*` at the end is always a good idea, I already did that. I prefer to keep `^` though, as a best practice. Sure, it can be removed here, too.